# ember model.get('elements.content.content') in setupController?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to update an ember 1.7 app. In setupController() of a route

`this.controllerFor('editor/object-list').set('model', model.get('elements.content.content'));`

gets called, and element.content.content seems to return an array of models. in 1.10 it returns undefined.

elements and elements.content return `<DS.PromiseManyArray:ember748>` and `<DS.ManyArray:ember749>`, but elements.content in 1.10 has no content property. In 1.7 it does. Instead 1.10 has canonicalState/currentState properties that seem to hold the data that is desired. I don't understand why this was even done this way. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: What are the Ember Data versions?

Comment: 1.0.0-beta.10 in the 1.7 Version and 1.0.0-beta.15 in the 1.10 Version

Comment: In the Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.14 release post here http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/12/25/ember-data-1-0-beta-14-released.html one of the comments below mentions a change to 'content'. Could you give us a bit more information on what elements is? Does `.set('model', model.get('elements'))` work?

Comment: .model.get('elements') does work, but then the attributes in some elements are undefined. I think they are set by computed.alias.

For elements I found: `Ember.computed.alias('controller.editorObjectList')`, which is an ArrayController

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `elements` is an async relationship, so you should resolve the promise:

```
model.get('elements').then(m => this.controllerFor('editor/object-list').set('model',m));
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning a promise in afterModel worked for me:

```
afterModel: function(sheet) {
    var elements = sheet.get('elements');
    var images = elements.map(function(e){ return e.get('image'); });

    return Ember.RSVP.all(images);
},
```